2023: a year in moderation

It’s that time of the year again! As we wave goodbye to last year and welcome the new one, we have a tradition of sharing moderation stats for the preceding calendar year.
As most of you here might be aware, sites on the Stack Exchange network are moderated somewhat differently to other sites on the web:

We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
-- A Theory of Moderation

That doesn't eliminate the need for having moderators altogether, but it does mean that the bulk of moderation work is carried out by regular folks — folks like you. Every bit of time and effort y'all contribute to the site gives you access to more privileges you can use to help in this effort, all of which produce a cumulative effect that makes a big difference in ensuring Stack Exchange sites remain a valuable source of high-quality content on the web.
So as we say goodbye to 2023 (and January 2024… ahem) and move into 2024, let us look back at what we accomplished as a community... by looking at some exciting stats. Below is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Cryptography over the past 12 months:




Action
Moderators
Community User¹
Community²




All comments on a post moved to chat
13
0
0


Answer flags handled
157
48
0


Answers flagged
2
52
150


Bounties canceled
1
0
0


Comment flags handled
43
35
0


Comments deleted⁸
833
8
909


Comments flagged
0
0
76


Comments undeleted
76
0
0


Escalations to the Community Manager team
1
0
0


Posts bumped
0
715
0


Posts deleted⁷
161
534
411


Posts locked
4
45
0


Posts undeleted
18
0
59


Posts unlocked
1
6
0


Question flags handled⁶
112
89
6


Questions closed
372
197
1


Questions flagged⁶
12
8
203


Questions merged
4
0
0


Questions migrated
29
0
0


Questions protected
0
3
0


Questions reopened
40
2
0


Questions unprotected
3
0
0


Revisions redacted
0
0
0


Tag highlight language set
0
0
0


Tag synonyms created
7
0
0


Tag synonyms proposed
4
0
3


Tags merged
0
0
0


Tasks reviewed⁵: "Close votes" queue
29
0
365


Tasks reviewed⁵: "First answers" queue
16
0
319


Tasks reviewed⁵: "First questions" queue
66
0
837


Tasks reviewed⁵: "Late answers" queue
2
0
144


Tasks reviewed⁵: "Low quality posts" queue
0
0
76


Tasks reviewed⁵: "Reopen votes" queue
7
0
36


Tasks reviewed⁵: "Suggested edits" queue
144
30
508


Tasks reviewed⁵: "Triage" queue
0
0
0


User banned from review
0
0
0


User review-bans lifted early
0
0
0


User suspensions lifted early
1
0
0


Users contacted
19
0
0


Users deleted
3
0
0


Users destroyed⁴
18
0
0


Users suspended³
14
45
0



Footnotes
¹ This refers to the automated systems otherwise known as user #-1.
² This refers to the membership of Cryptography without diamonds next to their names.
³ The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.
⁴ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.
⁵ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.
⁶ Includes close flags (but not close or reopen votes). The community² can handle these flags by at least one person voting to close a question that has a close flag.
⁷ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.
⁸ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).
Further reading:

Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? We posted a similar report here last year: 2022: a year in moderation

You can also check out this report on other sites

Or peruse detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites


Wishing everyone a happy 2024! ^_^

Happy 2024 to you too, JNat. 534 posts deleted by community, eh? Thanks for keeping our Q/A site safe! Especially since USENET is now officially dead. There are a few other archivers (hosted often by a single user), but the sci.crypto group is the last remnant, and looking at the posts I guess we can consider it deceased.
